# Framework version used by .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

I am trying to determine the version of the .NET framework that a dll is using. I have targeted 3.5 in my app but when I open the dll with `ildasm.exe` (on my dev PC with 3.5 installed), it says it is using `"Metadata version: v2.0.50727"` which is it really using?

Comment: Just because there's only one answer given doesn't mean you can't accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CLR version is `v2.0.50727` - this hasn't changed for .NET 3.5.

.NET 3.5 has added some DLLs and language support for C# 3.0, but the runtime has not changed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess the next question I would have is what actually happens when you "target" the 3.5 framework in VS, what does that actually do?

Comment: You should ask that as another question then ;)